# Cant use host-only adapter and bridged adapter at the same time virtual-box

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, virtualbox, openwrt

I want to create a virtual network that real devices can connect to using virtual box. I have 2 routers I am bridging to virtual firmware. I have servers also running on vm's and would like to be able to access them using devices connected to the routers eg. Android phones. I have all my virtual machines setup with host-only adapters and they can all ping each other. However, I cannot ping anything outside of the vm or host. Each router has an one adapter as host-only and the other as a bridged adapter.

My thinking was that I could use the bridge router and the host-adaper at the same time. However, this does not seem to be the case.

I'm wondering is it possible to do something of this nature with virtual box. 
Also if it is possible how should I succeed in implementing it.

Thanks in advance

---

**Diagrams and Additional information on network setup and my end goal**

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B3jfmn79Q_xxRFpYX3lDTnBaams&usp=sharing

**Open-wrt virtual firmware setup**

My current problem is that whichever adapter I use in the first tab named (Adapter 1) in the images above is the one that works. I need both adapters to work simultaneously. I'm not entirely sure what to do in the network configuration files either. In open-wrt the path to the network file is as follows /etc/config/network.

From my reading on the subject in the network file eth0 should correlate to Adapter 1 in the images above and eth1 as Adapter 2 and so on. Another problem that seems to be arising is that the last entry in the network config file is being taken as the eth0 interface, even though it is specified as eth1 as below.

**Access point 1 network config file shown below....access point 2 is the same but without eth1**

```
config interface lan
    option iframe      eth0
    option proto       static
    option ipaddr      192.168.1.100
    option netmask     255.255.255

config interface lan
    option iframe      eth1
    option type        bridge
    option proto       static
    option ipaddr      192.168.1.101
    option netmask     255.255.255.0
```

Not too sure what Im trying to achieve is even possible but thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: I've used guests with a NAT interface and a host-only interface at the same time without trouble. I doubt Virtualbox has any problem with using a bridged interface along with a host-only interface. But, you're using the same address range on both networks? That may be your problem. Try using a completely different address range for the host-only network.